# order different columns into one order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this;

```
Student_Name1   mark1  Student_Name2    mark2
-------------- ------ ---------------  --------
Kevin           77       Peter          78
Andrew          91       David          17
Scott           46       Bradley        28
```

How am i able to order `mark1` and `mark2` in the above table into descending order by including all the names and the points all together, like below?

```
Student_Name   mark
-------------- ------
Andrew          91
Peter           78
Kevin           77
Scott           46
Bradley         28
David           17
```

I am using MSSQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You've got some working answers below, but the real issue is your table structure, it'd be better to normalize it so that you had one student_name field, and you could add another field that would be used for identifying pairs, like a 'pair_id'.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `UNION ALL`:

```
Select    Student_Name1 As Student_Name,
          Mark1         As Mark
From      YourTable
Union All
Select    Student_Name2 As Student_Name,
          Mark2         As Mark
From      YourTable
Order By Mark Desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a strange table design but you can use `UNION` for this purpose like

```
select * from (
select Student_Name1 as Student_Name,  mark1 as mark from student
union all
select Student_Name2 ,  mark2 from student ) xxx
order by mark desc;
```